# How to "Integrate Along A Characteristic Curve"

Tags: calculus, integration, vectors

In The book "Handbook of Nuclear Engineering" by Dan Cauci, the following passage is shown on page 458.

[image]

What does he mean "integrate along the curve?"  As in a line integral?  What do I do with the dy and dx?

Answer (score 1):

It is a parametrisation: $x(s)$ is the $x$-position given $s$ and vice versa. It is fairly common to do this. See for instance http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/LineIntegralsPtI.aspx